# hide grid row based on visiblity of inside content

Tags: wpf, grid, height

I have a Grid with some rows. The height of the rows are set relatively to the window size like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" /> <!-- hide this row -->
        <RowDefinition Height="0.2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Now i want to hide the content of one row based on a binded property. Therefore I set the `Visiblity` Property of the content object to `Collapsed`. The `Visiblity` of the content works fine but the row still needs the original space.

Is there a way to hide the row when Visiblity of the content is collapsed? Note: I don't want to set the `Height` in the `RowDefinition` to `Auto` because so I can't set the `Height` relatively to the Window size and the height of the row gets adjustet to the height of the content inside the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the Height property of the row to the binded property.

Then you need a converter (implementation of IValueConverter) from typeof(binded property) to System.Windows.GridLength.

Perhaps something like

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(System.Windows.Visibility), typeof(System.Windows.GridLength))]
public class VisibToHeightConv : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool b = (boolean)value;

        if (b == true)
            return new System.Windows.GridLength(0, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Star);
        else
            return new System.Windows.GridLength(80, System.Windows.GridUnitType.Star);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The binded property is just a boolean value to set the Visiblity (with a boolean to visibilty converter).
The height of row should be depending on the height of the window.

Comment: Have a look at the converter for the row height